# com.parse.ParseRequest$ParseRequestException: bad json response (When I moved parse server to Heroku)

Tags: android, node.js, mongodb, heroku, parse-server

I have moved parse server on heroku and also database from parse.com to mangolab.
I'm getting following error when I make request from my android app.

```
com.parse.ParseRequest$ParseRequestException: bad json response
```

**App request**

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("sport");
            query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
''''''''''''
...........    
});
```

Note:
- 1. I'm using android parse sdk(v1.13.0) 
- 2. Android studio
- 3. My Parse initialization code is

```
Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
              .applicationId("mTAb2txgEHPy4fbxxxx").clientKey("KpKKNtKxxxxxPsppS0ovA")
                .server("http://raxxx-beyond-20009.herokuapp.com/parse").build());
```

- 4. I've added following Permission in Manifest file

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" 
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"
```

- 5. I've following below article and implemented everything like this. 
https://learnappmaking.com/how-to-migrate-parse-app-parse-server-heroku-mongolab/

- 5.1. I also also my mongodb connection string in my heroku account(heroku.com) and it is showing correct. 
- 5.1.2 - I also confirmed my heroku account url(that I'm passing during initialization of parse in point 3)

- 6. I have also tried to use parse android sdk (v1.12.0) but no success.(parse.initilize(........).server(....) is not implemented in this version)

-7. build.gradle(Module:app)

```
compile files('libs/Parse-1.13.0/Parse-1.13.0.jar')
```

Comment: Try app engine https://medium.com/google-cloud/deploying-parse-server-to-google-app-engine-6bc0b7451d50#.tnshf1tbe

Comment: Have you setup Parse Server on Heroku? That could be your issue. You need the NodeJS Parse API Server running to allow your app to connect to the Mongo database.

Comment: I have already setup Parse Server on Heroku. (I mentioned this in point 5)

Comment: See if this thread helps, especially the REST API mentioned. Can you see the JSON data that is sent back and forth? Use a proxy like Charles. https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-Android/issues/334

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to add an "/" to the end of your server-url. After /parse

Like this. 
"http://raxxx-beyond-20009.herokuapp.com/parse/"

Hope that helps.

Check out this issue for more information.
https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-Android/issues/382

Comment: It's so easy, but just easy to make mistake